# How to add and use tail in C list

Tags: c

So I am trying to create list. Function to add number on front of the list is working but I'm having trouble adding a number to the end of the list. I know that tail changes data value but I don't know how should i printf this and use it to change my list.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct list
{
    int data;
    struct lista *next;
};
struct listWsk
{
    struct list *head,*tail;
};
int create(struct listWsk *list, int data)
{
    struct list *new_front = malloc(sizeof(struct list));
    struct list *new_back = malloc(sizeof(struct list));
    if(NULL != new_front && NULL != new_back)
    {
        new_front->data = data;
        new_back->data = data;
        list->head = new_front;
        list->tail = new_back;
        list->tail->next = NULL;
        list->head->next = NULL;
        return 1;
    }
};
void print(struct listWsk list)
{
    while(list.head != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ",list.head->data);
        list.head = list.head->next;
    }
}
void front(struct listWsk *list, int data)
{
    struct list *new = malloc(sizeof(struct list));
    if(new != NULL)
    {
        new ->data = data;
        new ->next = list ->head;
        list ->head = new;
    }
};
void back(struct listWsk *list,int data)
{
    struct list *new = malloc(sizeof(struct list));
    if(new != NULL)
    {
        new -> data = data;
        new ->next = NULL;
       list ->tail->next = new;
       list->tail = new;
    }

}

int main()
{



    struct listWsk lista = {NULL,NULL};
    create(&lista,5);
    front(&lista,8);
    back(&lista,3);
    print(lista);


}
```

Output: 8 5 and I don't know how to add tail number to the list.

Comment: I understand why we should use tail pointer. It should skip the stage of searching for the last element but I don't understand how to use it

Comment: its very odd that your create 2 entries when you first create the list

Comment: It is in college tutorial how to make "guardians" that holds head and tail in list. I know how to make list but it contains "search tail" function and now I am trying to understand how to avoid it with *tail.

Comment: It makes sense to keep a pointer to the first and last element in the list. If there is only ONE item in the list, they should both point to the same item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corrected code

```
struct list
{
    int data;
    struct list* next; <<<<==== you had lista here - surpised it even compiled
};
struct listWsk
{
    struct list* head, * tail;
};
int create(struct listWsk* list, int data)
{
    // you dont need 2 nodes here just one
    // head and tail both point to it
    struct list* new_front = malloc(sizeof(struct list));
    if (NULL != new_front)
    {
        new_front->data = data;
        new_front->next = NULL;
        list->head = new_front;
        list->tail = new_front;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0; <<< === you were not returning a value here
};
void print(struct listWsk list)
{
    while (list.head != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ", list.head->data);
        list.head = list.head->next;
    }
}
void front(struct listWsk* list, int data)
{
    struct list* new = malloc(sizeof(struct list));
    if (new != NULL)
    {
        new->data = data;
        new->next = list->head;
        list->head = new;
    }
};
void back(struct listWsk* list, int data)
{
    struct list* new = malloc(sizeof(struct list));
    if (new != NULL)
    {
        new->data = data;
        new->next = NULL;
        list->tail->next = new;
        list->tail = new;

    }

}

int main()
{
    struct listWsk lista = { NULL,NULL };
    create(&lista, 5);
    front(&lista, 8);
    back(&lista, 3);
    // I added a few more test cases
    front(&lista, 81);
    back(&lista, 32);
    print(lista);


}
```

you problem was that you had 2 nodes instead of one in you list with 1 entry, things just got confused